# Can I put two Selects in a try?

Tags: java

```
try {
    Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/gym", "root", "0000");
    PreparedStatement inst = lig
            .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM produtos_has_historico WHERE Produtos_idProdutos AND Historico_idHistorico");


    ResultSet a = inst.executeQuery();
    while (a.next()){

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement(a);


    }               
} catch( Exception e ){}
```

In this Select, I get the `id historic` and the `id product`, but  I wanted to get also the name and price of the products that are in my other table "products" to add to my Jlist, can I use two selects ? Thank you.

Comment: Because of the connection between the program and the database

Comment: You can have a much as you want in a try block. Judi make sure you're able to tell which of them threw if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem to have two selects in a single try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the generated exception the same way regardless of where it occurred, then I don't see a problem with enclosing multiple statements in the same `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine to put multiple calls that may fail into a single `try/catch` block — in fact, that's a big part of why we *have* `try/catch` blocks (and exception handling in general), to move the code that handles *exceptional* things (failures) out of the way of the main code, so it's easier to understand the main code.

Compare these bits of pseudo-code

```
result = doThis();
if (result != success) {
    handleTheFailure(result)
} else {
    result = doThat();
    if (result != success) {
        handleThefailure(result);
    } else {
        result = doTheOther();
        if (result != success) {
            handleTheFailure(result);
        }
    }
}
```

vs.

```
try {
    doThis();
    doThat();
    doTheOther();
}
catch (failure) {
    handleFailure(failure);
}
```

More in [the Java tutorial on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html).

Answer (score 0):

No problem. I also recommend you use try-with-resources instead and be more specific about the exceptions you want to catch:

```
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...")) {

        PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("...");
        try (ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery()) {
            /* Parse first result */
        }

        PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("...");
        try (ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery()) {
            /* Parse second result */
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        for (Throwable t : ex) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for two selects - you can write a SQL query having a join in it .

You will be able to perform the join if you have common columns in your tables.

Then you can write a query using join and then the same code you can use to perform the operations and you can fetch all the values that you want.

For SQL joins basic - you can visit this site - 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: this will be a simpler approach rather than writing down two selects